# Definite Integral Approximation using the Trapezoidal Method

Tags: python, numerical-methods

I wrote a program to calculate the value of Definite Integral of a function from `a` to `b`. It used the trapezoidal approximation method where the function area is divided into 'n' trapeziums and area of each is added.

```
def calculate_area(f, a, b, n):
    # Trapezoidal approximation: divide area of function into n trapeziums and add areas. 
    # Large n value means better approximation

    # Finds the value of a definite integral from lower_lim (a) to upper_lim (b)
    # integral f(x) from lower_lim to upper_lim is =
    # 0.5 * w * ( f(a) + f(b) ) + <----- part_1
    # w * SUMMATION(x varies from 1 to n-1): f(a + x * w) <----- part_2
    # where w = (b - a) / n

    w = (b - a) / float(n) 
    part_1 = 0.5 * w * ( f(a) + f(b) )
    part_2 = 0
    for x in range(1, n):
        part_2 += f(a + x * w)
    part_2 *= w
    total_area = part_1 + part_2
    return total_area
```

For example, this can be used to calculate the area of a circle (or \$\pi\$ if the radius of the circle is 1):

> Consider the circle \$x^2 + y^2 = 1\$
>
> Area of this circle = \$\pi\$
>
> Expressed as a function of `x` is: `f(x) = (1 - x^2) ^ 0.5`
>
> Integrating this from `0` to `1` gives us a quarter of a circle whose
>   area is \$\frac\pi  4\$ (or the approximate value if we use approximate integration).
>
> On multiplying `4`, we get the value of \$\pi\$.
>
> Pass in the following as arguments :
>
> ```
> f = lambda x: (1 - x**2) ** 0.5; a = 0; b = 1
> ```

Now I face the following issues:

- Code is not very Pythonic.
- Code is not very efficient and fast.
- For better precision of PI value, the value of n must be increased. Python doesn't comply when n takes higher values (say 100 million). n = 10 million worked and I got a value of PI that was accurate upto 8 digits after the decimal.
- I feel that using floating point like datatypes which provide higher precision will increase precision of PI value. Correct me if I'm wrong.

I know that this is a very poor method of approximating the value of \$\pi\$ (this is the best I could come up with high school level knowledge). Let me know when I'm going to reach the limits. That is, when I will no longer be able to get noticeably more precise value of \$\pi\$.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If you are writing mathematical code in Python, then it is worth looking at [NumPy](http://www.numpy.org/), which is a library implementing (among other things) fast arithmetic operations on arrays of floating-point numbers.

In NumPy you'd write:

```
import numpy as np

def calculate_area(f, a, b, n):
    """Return an approximation to the definite integral of f from a to b
    using the trapezium rule with n intervals.

    """
    w = (b - a) / n                # width of the intervals
    x = np.linspace(a, b, n + 1)   # x coords of endpoints of intervals
    y = f(x)
    return w * (y.sum() - (y[0] + y[-1]) / 2)
```

Here [`np.linspace`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linspace.html) returns an array of numbers evenly spaced between two endpoints. For example, if we are asked to integrate between 0 and 1 with 4 intervals, then the endpoints of the intervals are:

```
>>> np.linspace(0, 1, 5)
array([0.  , 0.25, 0.5 , 0.75, 1.  ])
```

Under the assumption that `f` is a straightforward arithmetic function of its argument, then `f(x)` computes an array of the corresponding `y` values for each `x`. For example, if we have

```
def f(x):
    return x ** 2 + x + 1
```

Then:

```
>>> x = np.linspace(0, 1, 5)
>>> f(x)
array([1.    , 1.3125, 1.75  , 2.3125, 3.    ])
```

However, NumPy already has a built-in function [`np.trapz`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.trapz.html) that computes an integral using the trapezium rule. Using this function, we could write:

```
def calculate_area(f, a, b, n):
    """Return an approximation to the definite integral of f from a to b
    using the trapezium rule with n intervals.

    """
    x = np.linspace(a, b, n + 1)   # x coords of endpoints of intervals
    return np.trapz(f(x), x)
```

Comment: Using an external library would definitely make it much easier and efficient. Is there any library which you know that deals with higher precision floating point numbers. Plus, I can't compute the integral for larger values of n (say 100 million). Any solutions?

Comment: @PotCoder: (1) NumPy supports the "long double" data type, which varies according to the platform: on typical x86-64 machines, this is 80 bits. (2) Why would you want to make `n` so large?

Comment: Higher the n value. More accurate the integral value is. The actual purpose of this was to compute the value of pi. I'll add further details in the question.

Comment: Made some major revision. Please Check

Comment: @PotCoder - I have restored the original intent of the question to be about the more generic Trapezoidal Approximation, rather than specifically approximating \$\pi\$. Your edits went too far and changed the sense of the question too much, making other answers look incomplete. See [What you may and may not do after receiving answers](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1765)

Comment: @PotCoder: You would be very welcome to ask a new question with your revised code and a specific focus on computing π.

Comment: Sorry for making such major changes. Even I felt that some answers may seem incomplete. But I just feared how people would react if I were to create a new question based on the same topic.

Answer (score 8):

1. You can use `sum` with a comprehension to create `part_2`.
2. You can move all the maths together if you think it looks nicer.

```
def calculate_area(f, a, b, n)
    w = (b - a) / n
    return (
        0.5 * (f(a) + f(b))
        + sum(f(a + x * w) for x in range(1, n))
    ) * w
```

Comment: It appears too clustered. By the way, thanks for fixing all the typos. Can't believe I made so many mistakes while typing.

Answer (score 6):

If you want more accuracy than 8 or so digits, you probably will need a different method. The first obvious choice is Simpson's method, which approximates regions with parabolas instead of trapezoids. Better yet, check out this wikipedia article with a bunch of formulas for Pi. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Approximations_of_%CF%80. Specifically of interest is https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%E2%80%93Legendre_algorithm which shows a uses the following pseudocode gives the method

```
def calculate_pi(n):
    a = 1
    b = .5**.5
    t = .25
    p = 1
    for _ in range(n):
        a, b, t, p = a/2 + b/2, (a*b)**.5, t - p * (a/2 - b/2)**2, 2*p
    return (a + b)**2/(4*t)
```

`calculate_pi(3)=3.14159265358979323` (with a precise enough data type this should probably use `gmp` for better accuracy).

Even with python's limited float data type, this yields `3.141592653589794` which is just the limit of the datatype.

Using `gmpy2` to provide variable precision floats, we obtain the following

```
import gmpy2
from gmpy2 import mpfr

def calculate_pi(n):
    gmpy2.get_context().precision = 10*2**n
    a, b, t, p = mpfr(1), mpfr(.5)**mpfr(.5), mpfr(.25), mpfr(1)

    for _ in range(n):
        a, b, t, p = a/2 + b/2, (a*b)**.5, t - p * (a/2 - b/2)**2, 2*p
    return (a + b)**2/(4*t)
```

With `n=6`, this produces the first `171` digits in `0.00032782` seconds

Comment: Pretty much solves half of the updated problem. I wanted this and the solution given by Gareth Rees to be the accepted answer. I think I should've just made another question instead of completely changing the question.